# Cause of pytest ValueError: fixture is being applied more than once to the same function

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, pytest-fixtures

I have a unit test I'm running with a particular fixture. The fixture is pretty simple and looks like so:

```
@pytest.fixture
def patch_s3():
    # Create empty bucket
    bucket = s3_resource().create_bucket(Bucket=BUCKET)
    bucket.objects.all().delete()

    yield

    bucket.objects.all().delete()
```

and the test isn't all that complicated either. Here is the signature for the test:

```
def test_task_asg(patch_s3, tmp_path, monkeypatch)
```

However, when I run pytest, I get the following error:

```
tests/test_task_asg.py:313: in <module>
    @pytest.fixture
home/ubuntu/miniconda/envs/pipeline/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/fixtures.py:1150: in fixture
    fixture_function
home/ubuntu/miniconda/envs/pipeline/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/fixtures.py:1011: in __call__
    "fixture is being applied more than once to the same function"
E   ValueError: fixture is being applied more than once to the same function
```

This is weird to me, as it seems to imply I'm somehow including `patch_s3` more than once in `test_task_asg`. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you scroll up from your definition of `patch_s3`, you'll probably find another duplicate line like `@pytest.fixture`, causing the issue. That line can only be used once per fixture method definition.

The easiest way to reproduce this issue is with:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
@pytest.fixture
def my_fixture():
    yield

def test_abc(my_fixture):
    pass
```

Running that with `pytest` yields `ValueError: fixture is being applied more than once to the same function`. But if you remove one of the two `@pytest.fixture` lines, then the issue goes away.

Here are some examples where other people had the same issue and fixed it:

- https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/3518
- https://github.com/simonw/datasette/commit/969771770fcf795daace72e2310804e699067cfe
- https://github.com/RhodiumGroup/rhg_compute_tools/pull/67

Comment: Ah, you're totally right. I was looking for something in the signature itself, or something in the way I was running the tests. Good call. Based on my knowledge of SO's rules I think it makes sense to keep the question, as others may run into the same thing, and I didn't see a good SO dupe.